# Delegate += operator Class scope vs Local scope

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a delegate

```
delegate void Del(int a, int b);
```

why does this code works:

```
class MyClass
{
    private Del invoker;

    public void SetInvoker(Del del)
    {
        invoker += del; //everything is ok
    }
}
```

while this code doesn't?

```
 public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Del invoker += new Del(Display); //error! Invalid expression term '+='

        }

        static void Display(int a, int b)
        {

        }
    }
```

it's pretty strange because in both cases *invoker* is null before initializing (before using += operator)

Comment: `private static Del invoker;`

Comment: "this code doesn't" isn't a helpful problem description - especially when you should be getting a compiler error, include the *text* of the error message.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I added the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
Del invoker += new Del(Display);
```

is equal to

```
Del invoker;
invoker = invoker + new Del(Display);
```

Where the invoker can't be used in `+` operator because it is not initialized.

So

In the Main method your `invoker` is a local variable and every local variable must be initialized before using. `invoker`'s value is not `null`, but it is not **initialized**. If you doesn't assign **any value** to the variable, it will throw you an `error`, that it is not initialized. So you need to explicitly assign `null` to it.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Del invoker = null;
       invoker += new Del(Display); //error!
    }

    static void Display(int a, int b)
    {

    }
}
```

When you use the `class` version, `class'es` `constructor` will initialize the fields for first with their default values. So after the object creation, all it's fields have default values and so you can use `+=` with them.

Comment: yes, you are right, when I split initialization on two lines, now it tells right error message: "use of unsigned local variable". But if I have one line it says "Invalid expression term" - that's confusing

Comment: @Wachburn with one line the compiler knows that it is not initialized and doesn't understand the next operations. So it tell you to put `;`

Comment: maybe you wanted to say "Where the invoker CAN'T be used in + operator because...". By the way, why do you say invoker is null in the Main method? debugger shows it's set to null after declaring.

Comment: I said that invoker's value is **not** null

Comment: You can't use the assignment operators that modify the variable when you're **declaring** the variable, this is not specific to a delegate variable. You can't use `int x += 10;` either.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes you are right. I show it in the first part

Comment: sorry, I missed NOT in my comment. Why invoker is NOT null if debugger shows it's set to null?

Comment: when you only declare like this `Del invoker`, it can't be null, it is not initialized, and also you can't even enter in debug mode because you will have an compilation error. With the class example it will show null, because when you create an object it assigns the default values to the fields

Answer (score 1):

Well in the *erroneous code*, `invoker` is a *local vairable*

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Del invoker += new Del(Display); //error!
```

which has *not been initailized* and thus contains trash. You're
trying to add up `Display` to the garbage and so it's a error.

You have to *initialize* the `invoker`, which you can do in various ways:

```
   // Fields are initialized by default value; that's why invoker == null
   private static Del invoker;

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       invoker += new Del(Display);
```

Or

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       // just an assignment - notice = instead of +=
       Del invoker = new Del(Display);
```

Or

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Del invoker = null;
       invoker += new Del(Display);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` just works like any other operator. If the left operand and right operand have the correct types, it compiles.

In the first case, you add a `Del` (the parameter) to a variable in the class (`invoker`). This works because the types are correct.

But in the second case:

```
Del invoker += new Del(Display); //error!
```

Look closely at your code. `Del invoker` is a variable *declaration*. There is only one operator that can be placed after a variable declaration, and that is `=`. Your code does not work because of the same reason as why this does not work:

```
int a += 10;
```

So use `=` instead:

```
Del invoker = new Del(Display);
```

Comment: the reason why first example works is default constructor which sets invoker member to null. So in the second example we also need to initialize invoker with null before using += operator.

Comment: @Wachburn hmm... that's weird. I tried it on csharppad and it worked. Anyway, edited.